# Parcel Bundler - handle scss without resolving any urls in my sass

Tags: sass, parceljs

It's great that ParcelJS just handles sass out of the box but I'm running into a problem where it keeps throwing an exception when it encounters a url within in my scss file.  I guess Parcel is trying to locate the resource and rewrite the url.  I do **not** want Parcel to do this.  Is there anyway to disable this?  I just want it to compile the sass and leave any urls in there alone.

Comment: Can you provide examples of your parceljs setup and what errors you get?

Answer (score 2):

This question was posted when Parcel v1 was the latest version. For folks arriving here in the future, you can accomplish this in Parcel v2 with the [parcel-resolver-ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-resolver-ignore) plugin. Here's how:

1. Install it (e.g. `yarn add -D parcel-resolver-ignore`)
2. Create or modify your `.parcelrc` file to add it to the parcel pipeline:

   ```
   {
      "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
      "resolvers": ["parcel-resolver-ignore", "..."]
   }
   ```
3. Add a `"parcelIgnore"` entry to `package.json` that contains regex patterns that define which resources to ignore, e.g.:

   ```
   {
    // An array of Regex patterns
     "parcelIgnore": [
       "images\/*.*",
     ]
   }
   ```

The things you want to target your regexes to match are the urls referenced *in* the `.scss` files, *not* the `.scss` files themselves.